# What is PCXSTR, is it the same as LPCTSTR?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, mfc

This is a novice question, so please understand.

I tried to learn about `LPCTSTR`, `LPCWSTR`, etc, and I thought I understood these, and I learned the `T` means it varies according to the `UNICODE` setting.

But, I found `PCXSTR`, `PCYSTR`, etc in the ["`CStringT` Predefined Types"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170#cstringt-predefined-types) section in the `CStringT` documentation.

Here are several questions.

1. What are `PCXSTR`, `PCYSTR`, `XCHAR`, `YCHAR`, etc, and what's their relationship with `LPCTSTR`, `TCHAR`, etc?
2. What does *'same/opposite character type'* mean in the above MSDN section?
3. There is `CSimpleStringT::operator PCXSTR()` in the source code (`atlsimpstr.h`). When I write some code like `myCString.operator LPCWSTR();`, it seems like it's the same as `myCString.operator PCXSTR();` (Visual Studio 'Go to definition' takes me to the `operator PCXSTR()`, not to `operator LPCWSTR()`). VS even suggests only `operator LPCWSTR`, not `operator PCXSTR`. So, is `LPCWSTR` (which is the same as `LPCTSTR` in my Unicode setting) the same as `PCXSTR`? What's going on here?

Comment: 1.: Orthogonal types; they obviously are template class related types and do not depend on `UNICODE`, but on the `BaseType` the template class `CStringT` was instantiated with. 2.: With `BaseType` being `char` same is `char`, opposite `wchar_t`, analgously for `wchar_t` as `BaseType.`

Comment: 3. Should only be the same for `BaseType` being `wchar_t`.

Comment: Don't know how they actually achieve, but I'd assume something equivalent to `using XCHAR = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<wchar_t, BaseType>, wchar_t, char>;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for illustration (`CStringT` reduced to the absolutely necessary, it actually has a second template parameter; and just a demonstration, actual implementation most likely looks differently):

```
#if UNICODE
#define TCHAR wchar_t
#else
#define TCHAR 
#endif

template <typename BaseType>
class CStringT
{
public:
    using XCHAR
      = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<wchar_t, BaseType>, wchar_t, char>;
    using YCHAR
      = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<wchar_t, BaseType>, char, wchar_t>;
};
```

Details might differ, especially the real `CStringT` implementation, but at least they would do something semantically equivalent.

`TCHAR` is relying only on `UNICODE` being enabled or not – the `X/YCHAR` types in contrast are independent from and depend on the type `CStringT` was instantiated with. The meaning of self and opposite should be obvious from the code snippet above, too.

Actually there are *three*, not two, independent (relevant) character aliases:

```
TCHAR
CStringT<char>::XCHAR
CStringT<wchar_t>::XCHAR
```

Accordingly `CStringT<char>::PCXSTR` is equivalent to `LPCSTR` while in contrast `CStringT<wchar_t>::PCXSTR` is equivalent to `LPCWSTR`.

Finally you could base the string type on `UNICODE` being enabled by `CStringT<TCHAR>` resulting in `PCXSTR` being equivalent to `LPCTSTR`.

Comment: I've never seen `CString` being implemented depending on the `std` library, and I didn't touch MFC for a while. Perhaps this is something new. Since what version are things like this?

Comment: @sergiol This is just for demonstration, note *'something semantically equivalent'* – I even pretty much assume `CStringT` actually is *not* implemented like this because they possibly might need to cover standards older than C++11. That might look e.g. like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nPnTKre33), but there are numerous other possibilities as well...

Comment: Since `CString`'s baseType is `TCHAR`, at least `CString`'s `XCHAR`(and other `X`s such as `PCXSTR`, etc.) is up to UNICODE, is that right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @starriet That's the consequence of, indeed ;)